# How to pass NULL value for integer/fixnum type in ruby for SOAP request

Tags: ruby, soap, null, wsdl

I need to invoke the method `getquotedata()` through a SOAP request using the parameters:

`username`, `password`, `id`, `revnum`

`revnum` is the revision number of the data we are fetching. It can have values like `... 1,2,3...` and so on. If we pass a null value to it, we get the latest data.

How can I initialize an Integer with null value in ruby for the method call? The method call does not work if we pass `nil` to `revnum` or even if we do not send this parameter. Below is our sample method call:

```
getQuoteData(:username => user, :password=> pass, id => "XKS32", revnum=> 0)
```

The WSDL definition of the method is:

```
<s:element name="GetQuoteData">
  <s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="username" type="s:string" /> 
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="password" type="s:string" /> 
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="cartCompositeNumber" type="s:string" /> 
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="revNum" nillable="true" type="s:int" /> 
    </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: WSDL <s:element name="GetQuoteData"><s:complexType><s:sequence><s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="username" type="s:string"/><s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="password" type="s:string"/><s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="cartCompositeNumber" type="s:string"/><s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="revNum" nillable="true" type="s:int"/></s:sequence></s:complexType>

Comment: 1. which soap client are you using to execute `getQuoteData` and 2. if your webservice is public, please post it's address for testing purposes.